# Is it possible to override system directory separator character for IO classes in C#?

Tags: c#, path, filesystems

I'm developing in Unity 3D and sometimes writing Editor tools. Sometimes I meet the problem with directory separator character. Unity API always uses '/' for example to request AssetDatabase paths. But IO classes such as File, Directory or Path use system separator, so it is '\' on Windows and '/' on macOS. Is it possible to make them use '/' by default even on Windows? Maybe there is some filed I can initialize at the runtime initizlization stage? It is annoying to replace '\' by '/' everytime to unify API calls. My code looks like this now and it's ugly I think:

```
foreach (var prefabPath in prefabPaths)
{
#if UNITY_EDITOR_WIN
    prefabPath = prefabPath.Replace('\\', '/');
#endif
    .............
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is the best way to do it with the least amount of added logic. I can help you touch it up a bit.

```
//using System;
//using System.IO;

foreach (string _preFabPath in PreFabPaths)
{
#if UNITY_EDITOR_WIN
    _preFabPath = _preFabPath.Replace(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, '/');
#endif
}
```

- DirectorySeparatorChar will use the path separator native to the system you are on.
- Underscoring encapsulated privates will help identify preFabPath as a ForEach encapsulated variable.

Comment: Yes, it seems this is the only way.